# C# - Unity - Problem with Parameter passing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parameters

I'm trying to extract a lot of code in my program and I encountered a problem.

This is my function to extract a smelting process:

```
public IEnumerator Smelting(Button button, Image bar, BigDouble material, BigDouble output)
    {
        button.interactable = false;

        float t = 0f;
        while (t <= 1f)
        {
            bar.fillAmount = t;
            t += Time.deltaTime / 4;
            yield return null;
        }

        bar.fillAmount = 0;
        //saveLoadHandler.data.copperBar += smeltingHandler.smeltCopperOreOutput;
        material += output;
        button.interactable = true;
    }
```

My Problem is now that I want to add the output to the material with:  `material += output`.
The Command above shows what these parameter look like.

So it looks like in this case the `material` doesn't get assigned correctly.

I don't want to go the way `if(type = copper){copper += output } else if(type = iron)...`

Is there a workaround for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a few key-points missing. This is a function with a `yield return`. How do you call it? How exactly is `+=` implemented for `BigDouble`?

Comment: I call it like this `StartCoroutine(smeltingCore.Smelting(smeltCopperOreButton, smeltCopperOreBar, saveLoadHandler.data.copperBar, smeltingHandler.smeltCopperOreOutput));` The BigDouble is this one "https://github.com/Razenpok/BreakInfinity.cs" it is basically the same like a normal double

Comment: But the problem isn't about the yield return or something. I think it is a basic c# problem. I can't add the output value to the material value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `BigDouble` is just like a normal `double`, it is a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types), and is therefore being passed by value to your method. You can add the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword to pass it by reference:

```
public IEnumerator Smelting(Button button, Image bar, ref BigDouble material, BigDouble output)
```

However, iterators cannot have ref arguments, so another workaround might be to pass a delegate to the method who's job it is to increment something

```
public IEnumerator Smelting(Button button, Image bar, Action<BigDouble> incrementMaterial, BigDouble output) {
    ....
    incrementMaterial(output); // instead of material += output
    ....
}
```

and then the caller:

```
StartCoroutine(smeltingCore.Smelting(
     smeltCopperOreButton, 
     smeltCopperOreBar, 
     amount => saveLoadHandler.data.copperBar += amount, 
     smeltingHandler.smeltCopperOreOutput));
```

Of course, at this point you're only passing in `output` to use it in the delegate so you can simplify both:

```
public IEnumerator Smelting(Button button, Image bar, Action incrementMaterial) {
    ....
    incrementMaterial(); 
    ....
}
```

and

```
StartCoroutine(smeltingCore.Smelting(
     smeltCopperOreButton, 
     smeltCopperOreBar, 
     () => saveLoadHandler.data.copperBar += smeltingHandler.smeltCopperOreOutput 
     ));
```

Comment: If i use it it says "Iterators cannot have any ref parameters". Any Idea?

Comment: @Timebreaker900 of course not, silly me. See update.